# Generating 3D models / meshes

Tags: java, libgdx, procedural-generation, 3d-meshes, mesh

In LibGDX how can I construct a 3D terrain model that has

- Position
- Normal
- Color

The model does not require a texture, it is colored on a per vertex basis.
I've looked into LibGDX's [ModelBuilder](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/ModelBuilder.html) and [MeshPartBuilder](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshPartBuilder.html), but I can't seem to get it to work. I suspect this is a problem with indexing since I'm inexperienced on the subject.

So the question boils down to; **In LibGDX, given positions (x, y, z), normals (nx, ny, nz), color (r, g, b, a) how can I construct a mesh / model with these vertex attributes and properly index them?**

What I've tried so far:

```
final int attributes = Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.ColorPacked;
partBuilder = modelBuilder.part("Terrain", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attributes, material);

/*Generate vertices*/
for (int i = 0; i < VERTEX_COUNT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < VERTEX_COUNT; j++) {
        final float x = j / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        final float z = i / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        final float y = MathUtils.random() * 10; // Testing different heights
        /*Position at (x,y,z), normal generated automatically*/
        partBuilder.vertex(new Vector3(x, y, z), null, Color.WHITE, null);
    }
}

/*Generate indices*/
for (short gz = 0; gz < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gz++) {
    for (short gx = 0; gx < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; gx++) {
        final short topLeft = (short) ((gz * VERTEX_COUNT) + gx);
        final short topRight = (short) (topLeft + 1);
        final short bottomLeft = (short) (((gz + 1) * VERTEX_COUNT) + gx);
        final short bottomRight = (short) (bottomLeft + 1);
        partBuilder.index(topLeft, bottomLeft, topRight, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as I expected and generates the following result:
[image]